# How can I solve this syntax error in my JSON object?

Tags: javascript, python, json, syntax, runtime-error

First and foremost, I'd like to address that JSON is fairly new to me so expect my code to look faulty. I have a JSON object that defines two clubs: "Oak Club" and "Bravo Club" with its members. Note, that this code was written in Python.

Here is the JSON object:

```
json_clubs = {
    "clubs": [
        {
            "Oak Club": {
                    "members": [
                        "Charles",
                        "Nora",
                        "Tom",
                        "Paul"
                        ]
                    }
            }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Bravo Club": {
                "members": [
                    "Nathaniel",
                    "Roselyn",
                    "Ash"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

This code raises the syntax error: ':' expected after dictionary key.

VSCode highlights the "clubs" key-value pair and states: End of file expected.

After inspecting my code, I can't seem to figure out where I went wrong since all my keys have colons separating keys from their values.

Comment: remove the `]` before the `Bravo Club` and move it to just before the last `}`

Comment: That is a regular dictionary, not a JSON object

Comment: Since you are already using VSCode, I strongly recommend that you enable the built-in [Bracket Pair Colorizer](https://dev.to/vscodetips/native-bracket-pair-colourization-in-vs-code-3f1n). That way, it is much easier to work with brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to map `clubs` to two separate arrays (each containing a single object), rather than a single array with two objects.

```
json_clubs = {
    "clubs": [
        {
            "Oak Club": {
                    "members": [
                        "Charles",
                        "Nora",
                        "Tom",
                        "Paul"
                        ]
                    }
        },
        {
            "Bravo Club": {
                "members": [
                    "Nathaniel",
                    "Roselyn",
                    "Ash"
                    ]
                }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than including the two club objects inside of the `clubs` array, you only adding the `Oak Club` object to it and then defining another array to the JSON object that is anonymous. Here's a better way to structure that code:

```
json_clubs = {
    "clubs": [
        {
            "Oak Club": {
                "members": [
                    "Charles",
                    "Nora",
                    "Tom",
                    "Paul"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "Bravo Club": {
                "members": [
                    "Nathaniel",
                    "Roselyn",
                    "Ash"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Line 13 you're closing the array instead of the object.

```py
json_clubs = {
  "clubs": [
    {
      "Oak Club": {
        "members": [
          "Charles",
          "Nora",
          "Tom",
          "Paul"
        ]
      },
      "Bravo Club": {
        "members": [
          "Nathaniel",
          "Roselyn",
          "Ash"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current format, you are missing a key and colon for the second item. WIthout changing it, you would fix by entering its key here:

```
json_clubs = {
    "clubs": [
        {
            "Oak Club": {
                    "members": [
                        "Charles",
                        "Nora",
                        "Tom",
                        "Paul"
                        ]
                    }
            }
    ],
    "KEY NAME GOES HERE" : [
        {
            "Bravo Club": {
                "members": [
                    "Nathaniel",
                    "Roselyn",
                    "Ash"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

However, based on the item names, it appears that maybe something like this would be the more appropriate solution.

```
json_clubs = {
  "clubs": [
    {
      "Oak Club": {
        "members": [
          "Charles",
          "Nora",
          "Tom",
          "Paul"
        ]
      },
      "Bravo Club": {
        "members": [
          "Nathaniel",
          "Roselyn",
          "Ash"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```